# When exporting data from CheckBox field, can value of be different from what is displayed?

Tags: custom-fields, database, export

When exporting data from a custom CheckBox field, can the value of the data exported be different from what is displayed?  For example, the checkbox Multiple choice is labeled "Asked"  but I would like the data value exported to be 1.  I tried to change the Value to 1, but it is still exporting "Asked"

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Christine, welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange. I am sorry but I am unclear if you are asking how to do this or if you would suggest this as an improvement? And waht version of CiviCRM are you using? How exactly are you exporting  your data? Answering these questions will help folks here to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Civi I am using, but I think a pretty current one. We just updated.  I'm not a programmer, just a user.   I would like to know how to export the Value of the data filed instead of the label is that is possible.  These are custom fields in an Activity.  I am doing a Find Activities, then exporting the data that way.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know you can not change the way an exported field is represented in the User Interface.
What you could do is create a report of activities and export that report, perhaps you will then get the option to get the value. And this extension might help as well: https://civicrm.org/extensions/export-native-excel. Good luck!